# What's wrong with my post?

Tags: discussion

[How long does it take to convert a cdr to an iso?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/346595/how-long-does-it-take-to-convert-a-cdr-to-an-iso/346598#346598)

I believe this is the correct answer. I've successfully use similar commands as shown in the article.

Why are people so negative?  They are not providing any answers.  It's easy to complain.

There should be a requirement that people explain themselves when they downvote something.  How am I to improve?

Comment: The main problem I see here is that with hindsight it might have been better to put the question on hold for being unclear, especially after the OP decided to not provide more clarifications either in the comments or by editing the question. With unclear questions any answer can be right or wrong (or both), and will attract downvotes for various reasons.

Comment: Do you not feel that the reasons stated in the highest voted comment on your answer are sufficient to explain the downvotes? While I have not voted either way on the answer in question, the concern about piping dd to dd seems legitimate.

Answer (score 4):

In the Stack Exchange community (and espically so in Ask Different) we have what I like to affectionately call "the voting horde."  And within this horde there are two factions, the "up vote brigade" and the "down vote posse."

I have literally seen questions which were not only off topic for having nothing to do with Apple products but actually make no sense receive what seems like the "automatic up vote" and answers which are well thought out and reasoned get down voted faster than quick.

It's the nature of the  beast.

It's happened to me several times as it's happened to countless others.  Don't allow it to discourage you - just put in your best and honest effort and pay them no mind.  Your efforts will speak for itself and don't worry, veterans like myself will share with you what we find wrong (and in many cases what's *right*!) in your post (without the down vote, ironically).

Don't forget, it takes 5 down votes to cancel one up vote.

There's an old adage that I heard years back that applies to situations like this:

*It takes a craftsman to build something, but any mule can knock it down.*

As for what's wrong with you post?

Nothing. Keep being the craftsman.

Comment: Statistically you rightly observe that brigade and posse cancel each other out for most of the posts and rep-hunters remain comfy (HNQ-effects excluded). But apart from really deserving posts the posse makes life miserable and *really* destroys some functionality here in that 'good' or 'OK' answers *do not* rise-to-the-top as fast as they could or should. Grumpy posse would not be that much of an issue here, and that one is biiig, if more people (eg veterans, nudge, nudge) would vote more, and vote more positively, if appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't answer the question, in part because the question doesn't make sense.  (I just attempted to write my own answer, but as I explained within it, I'm stuck guessing what the asker is trying to do.)  There are numerous hints in the question and subsequent comments that the asker found the wrong command for the job.  The command they're running does something completely different from what they want to do, so asking why it's taking a long time isn't useful.  When they try your command, it's still not going to do what they want.

There are some terminology issues with your post.  I wouldn't warrant that worthy of a downvote--yes, `bs` actually stands for block size, but it probably also affects the buffer size.

It's definitely not a great idea to pipe dd directly to another dd process, though I see where you got the idea; in your example, you've got another command in between.  However, the example provided by the asker indicates that there's no need for an intermediary command--or, at least, that would be what it indicated if they were on the right track, which they're not.

When someone asks the wrong question, answers are inevitably going to be controversial.  Opinions vary widely on how you should proceed.  Some would rather that ignore the discrepancies and attempt to answer the literal question, thereby helping people who arrive from search engines.  Others would rather that you read into the asker's intentions and provide an answer that helps the asker, rather than people arriving from Google.  Still others want you to leave a comment and downvote the question.

In this scenario, there's no winning answer.  You can see that my answer was almost immediately downvoted.  It's probably going to continue to get downvoted.

Edit: I just saw someone mention the term "[XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)" elsewhere on AskDifferent.  It's a pretty fitting explanation for the problem here.

Comment: I can only repeat what I commented on your answer already: If in doubt, add a comment, not a answer making too many assumption. Or flag for mod attention. Or just ignore it.

Comment: And remember: There are no wrong questions. There may be questions though which are not as clear to understand to the reader as to the writer.

Comment: The threshold for “too many assumptions” is fairly subjective; it also varies by community. On Stack Overflow, answers like that are common because people often don’t ask the right question. Sometimes it’s impossible to tell what they’re trying to do, but when there’s a reasonable guess to be made, there’s no harm in posting an answer. The answer I wrote wouldn’t have fit in a comment, it does answer the literal question (“how long should it take?”), and it attempts to provide additional help. (Note that OP didn’t ask how to speed it up, only how long it should take.)

Comment: There are definitely wrong questions. If you’re trying to do X, but you ask how to do Y, and Y can’t lead you to X, it is quite objectively the wrong question. It could still be a valid question, but the asker probably isn’t going to appreciate a valid answer. My general approach there is to provide both the valid answer and “If you’re trying to do XYZ, you may need to ask a different question”—otherwise, they’re just going to be frustrated.

Comment: "If you’re trying to do XYZ, you may need to ask a different question" is something not everybody appreciates, especially if they *want* to do XYZ and believe that they asked the right question already. These situations are usually better handled in comments, guesswork answers tend to attract more downvotes than they deserve.

Comment: Alright, I suppose I’ll edit it.

Comment: I though your answer was good.  Gives a lot of background information.  Folks, it's easy to nitpick.

Comment: In hindsight, after re-reading my post, I have to agree with @nohillside; I made too many assumptions and jumped to conclusions.  The current version is a lot better.